# C++ high_resolution_clock weird output

Tags: c++, time, clock, timedelta, delta

I am currently trying to calculate the delta time of a loop in cpp. Currently i use this code

```
#include <chrono>
int main()
{

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
typedef std::chrono::duration<float> fsec;

auto lastTime = Clock::now();
auto currentTime = Clock::now();
fsec passedTime = currentTime - lastTime;
while (true)
{
    lastTime = currentTime;
    printf("");
    printf("");
    printf("");
    printf("");
    printf("");
    printf("");
    printf("");
    printf("");
    printf("");
    printf("");
    currentTime = Clock::now();
    passedTime = currentTime - lastTime;
    printf("%i\n", passedTime.count());
}

return 0;
}
```

***This is not the actual code i use in the program but the delta time calculation and the output is the exact same as in this sample.***

It used to work fine and output a number of about ~0.0167 when locked to 60 ticks/s by GLFW and a ways lower number that at about 6k ticks/s.

My Problem is that I shifted everything out of the main function into a method and now get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNJrF.png)

It seems like I changed something by mistake but I can't figure out what I've changed.

Comment: _***This is not the actual code i use in the program ...***_ Post a [MCVE] please or it didn't happen!

Comment: the output is the exact same too. this fully replicates the problem. my fault for not clarifyng enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your printf is wrong, the data is a float, but the printf format is an int.

Comment: Thanks, first time using printf, didn't know there were specific formats.

Comment: You should probably use the c++ stream operators, then you don't need to worry about types so much, something like : `std::cout << passedTime.count() << std::endl;`